# multiple file handlers in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to have multiple pages in google-app engine (python 2.7) and the followoing is my directory structure: 
root contains: pujaweb.py (the main script), index.html, stylesheets(folder), port(folder)...

now my second script for the page is in the port folder and i want to configure my index.html such that it links to that page. I have tried a lot of stuff but somehow it does not work and always shows 404 page not found error and the command line says that PujaPort module does not exist (pujaport being the app handler for the second page).

the following is my app.yaml file code:

```
application: thepujabhalerao

version: 1

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: true



handlers:

- url: /images

  static_dir: images





- url: /stylesheets

  static_dir: stylesheets


- url: /port
  script: pujaport.app


- url: /.*

  script: pujaweb.app



libraries:

- name: jinja2

  version: latest
```

this is my main handler (pujaweb.py)

```
import cgi

import webapp2 

import jinja2

import os

from google.appengine.api import xmpp

from google.appengine.ext import db





jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(

    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))



class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):

      template_values = {}

      template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')

      self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))




app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],

                              debug=True)
```

and the href in the index filer looks like this:

```
<a href="/port/">P</a>
```

and finally this is the second page handler pujaport.py:

```
    import cgi

import webapp2 

import jinja2

import os

from google.appengine.api import xmpp

from google.appengine.ext import db





jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(

    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))



class PujaPort(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):

        self.response.out.write("In handler")




app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/port', PujaPort)],

                              debug=True)
```

I know its a minor glitch somewhere but please help me out as after being on it for too long i maybe missing the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using that folder structure, you'll need to make the `port` directory into a package by adding an `__init__.py` file to it (which can be empty), and reference the app as `port.pujaport.app`, its fully qualified name.

Comment: I followed your instrucitons, still getting 404 not found.
My directory structure 
   test_app/
      - app.yaml
     + login/
     + logout/
      - main.py

app.yaml contents
application: testing
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /login/.*
  script: login.login.app

- url: /logout/.*
  script: logout.logout.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
please help me out.